# MagicalRecord and Swift

Tags: swift, magicalrecord

I have a swift project, and I've pulled in the MagicalRecord ObjectiveC source into it.

I've created the Bridging-Header and it's compiling fine, and auto complete work's etc...

However, at runtime it crashes immediately with unrecognised selector for the first magical record category that it encounters.

Is there a step I'm missing when using objective-c in a swift project?

Comment: Schoolboy error... was missing my -ObjC linker flag to pull in the categories

Answer (score 2):

Forgot the add the -ObjC flag to the Other Linker Flags to pull in the categories into the binary.

Answer (score 0):

if your `NSManagedObject` subclasses is swift code then you have to give them full class names. First create `NSManagedObject` subclasses. Then in model editor change your every entities class name to `YourProjectTargetName.ClassName`. For example I have a project called BucketList and an entity `Target` it class name must be `BucketList.Target`. You can set class name in data model inspector.